# GCC compiler and converting const char* to char *

Tags: c, gcc, build, literals

I am trying to build the M-SIM architecture simulator, but when I run the make utility, gcc reports this error (it is not even a warning)

note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'

Since when this is considered an error. Is there any flags that can bypass this check?

Comment: You probably shouldn't ignore the warning; don't pass a string literal to a function expecting a modifiable buffer

Comment: Search gcc's info page for `-fno-const-strings` which echos Seth's sentiment.

Comment: Show us the code that triggers the error. In C, string literals are not `const`. And show us (copy and paste) the exact error message; I don't recall seeing a gcc error message starting with "note".

Comment: `char*` to `const char*` is always valid, but `const char*` to `char*` is not. There is an exception made when passing string literals; this is what gcc is reporting. You shouldn't ignore it though.

Comment: Correction: gcc does produce that message.  See my answer.

Comment: @zneak there is no exception regarding string literals, string literals are of type array N of `char` and not `const` array N of `char`.

Comment: @ouah, you're right, they are not constant. It should be noted that some operating systems will map the section in which string literals reside on read-only memory, and that any attempt to modify characters of a string literal will result in a bus error.

Comment: @zneak yes, because string literals are not required to be modifiable.   Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: @keeto For C in GCC, you can use -Wwrite-strings to give string literals the type "const char*" to produce the warning. Did you have that warning turned on when any of your code or library code was compiled? If not, GCC should not be producing the warning. In reply to honk, -fno-const-strings is a C++ option deprecated in GCC 3.x and removed from 4.x.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an error because passing a `const char*` argument to a function that takes a `char*` parameter violates const-correctness; it would allow you to modify a `const` object, which would defeat the whole purpose of `const`.

For example, this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *s) {
    puts(s);
    s[0] = 'J';
}

int main(void) {
    const char message[] = "Hello";
    func(message);
    puts(message);
    return 0;
}
```

produces the following compile-time diagnostics from gcc:

```
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:10:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
c.c:3:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
```

The final message is marked as a "note" because it refers to the (perfectly legal) declaration of `func()`, explaining that that's the parameter declaration to which the warning refers.

As far as the C standard is concerned, this is a constraint violation, which means that a compiler *could* treat it as a fatal error.  gcc, by default, just warns about it and does an implicit conversion from `const char*` to `char*`.

When I run the program, the output is:

```
Hello
Jello
```

which shows that, even though I declared `message` as `const`, the function was able to modify it.

Since gcc didn't treat this as a fatal error, there's no need to suppress either of the diagnostic messages.  It's entirely possible that the code will work anyway (say, if the function doesn't happen to modify anything).  But warnings exist for a reason, and you or the maintainers of the M-SIM architecture simulator should probably take a look at this.

(Passing a string literal to `func()` wouldn't trigger these diagnostics, since C doesn't treat string literals as `const`.  (It does make the behavior of attempting to modify a string literal undefined.)  This is for historical reasons.  gcc does have an option, `-Wwrite-strings`, that causes it to treat string literals as `const`; this actually violates the C standard, but it can be a useful check.)

As I mentioned in a comment, it would be helpful if you'd show us the code that triggers the diagnostics.

I even downloaded and built the M-SIM architecture simulator myself, but I didn't see that particular message.

Comment: dear Keith, what about vice versa, is passing char pointer to function expecting const char pointer also constraint violation? why not? Also case Nr. 2 what happens if I pass const char pointer to function which expects char pointer - but the function doesn't modify the data pointer to, is it also constraint violation?

Comment: @Giorgi: No, that's not a constraint violation, and it's perfectly valid. For example, `strlen` takes a `const char*`, but you can pass it a `char*` that points to a modifiable array. You can modify the array if you like, but `strlen` won't.

Comment: So passing char* to function expecting const char * is fine, but vice versa not? Even if function will not modify data pointed to

Comment: @Giorgi: Yes. Why wouldn't it be? You don't *have* to modify the data.

Answer (score 5):

Pointers to `const`-qualified types do not implicitly convert to pointers to non-`const`-qualified types. An explicit conversion via a cast is necessary, for example:

```
foo((char *)bar)
```

Comment: This could be dangerous if `bar` was in fact a constant char pointer.

Comment: What's necessary in most cases is fixing the code so that you don't have to use a cast.

Comment: Not sure what the -1's for.. I agree OP is probably doing something wrong, but it's impossible to tell from the question, and at least I'm not making bogus assumptions (like lots of other ppl) that the expression in question is a string literal with `-fconst-strings` specified...

Answer (score 4):

First in a function call (of a function defined with a prototype), the arguments are converted to the type of the parameters as if by assignment.

You can assign a value of type `char *` to an object of type `const char *` but you cannot assign a `const char *` value to a `char *` object.

This constraint appears in the constraints of assignment operator:

> (C99, 6.5.16.1p1) "One of the following shall hold: [...] - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;"

This constraint permits the first assignment but disallows the second.

Declaring a pointer with type `const char *` means you won't modify the object pointed to by the pointer. So you can assign the pointer a value of `char *` type, it just means the object won't be modified through the `const char *` pointer.

But declaring a pointer of type `char *` means you could modify the object pointed to by the pointer. It would not make sense to assign it a value of `const char *`.

Remember that in C, `const` does not mean *constant* but rather *read-only*. The `const` qualifier put before pointer types means you promise not to modify objects through objects of these pointers types.

Answer (score 0):

Take these steps if you haven't already:

1. Declare a char pointer.
2. If necessary, allocate space and copy contents from the constant string. (e.g. by
   using `strdup()`)
3. And substitute the constant char pointer with the new char pointer.

Comment: And, if you allocated the space with `strdup()`, don't forget to free it when you're finished with it.